# Accessing parent function from JavaScript object

Tags: javascript, scope

How would I do the following:

```
var Parent = function() {
 this.Child = {
    childFunction: function() {
      this.parentFunction();
    }
  };
  this.parentFunction = function() {

  }
};
var parentObj = new Parent();
parentObj.Child.childFunction();
```

At the moment I'm getting "undefined is not a function" because obviously parentFunction() isn't in scope, but I'm not sure what the best way to make it accessible is?

Answer (score 1):

As `this` in `Child` will refer to `Child` object not `Parent` thus Store the reference of `this` of `Parent` in a variable which can be used later in `childFunction`.

```js
var Parent = function() {
  var _self = this; //Store the reference
  this.Child = {
    childFunction: function() {
      _self.parentFunction(); //Use here
    }
  };
  this.parentFunction = function() {
    alert('In parentFunction');
  }
};
var parentObj = new Parent();
parentObj.Child.childFunction();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var Parent = function() {
 this.Child = {
    childFunction: function() {
      this.parentFunction();
    }
  };
  this.parentFunction = function() {

  }
};
```

Now inside `this.Child childFunction` this will refer to Child object and not the Parent.

So you must use self/that to refer to the parent.

```
 var Parent = function() {
     var that = this;
     this.Child = {

        childFunction: function() {
          that.parentFunction();
        }
      };
      this.parentFunction = function() {

      }
    };
```

You can just use Parent.parentFunction() as well.

```
 var Parent = function() {
     this.Child = {

        childFunction: function() {
          Parent.parentFunction();
        }
      };
      this.parentFunction = function() {

      }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `this` in your `childFunction` refers to the current object which is `Child`.

The common solution would be to access the parent using a variable that is available through a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures). For example:

```
var Parent = function() {
    var _this = this;

    this.Child = {
       childFunction: function() {
          _this.parentFunction();
       }
     };

    this.parentFunction = function() {
        // ...
    }
};
```

Alternatively, a more cumbersome approach would be to use [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to 'tie' the function context of the `childFunction` to the current `this` (which is the parent):

```
childFunction: function() {
    this.parentFunction();
}.bind(this);
```

See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)